# Symmetric difference and Measurability

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{M},\mu)$ a measure space. Declare sets $E_1,E_2 \in \mathcal{M}$ to be equivalent if $\mu(E_1\Delta E_2)=0$ where $\Delta$ denotes the symmetric difference. Show that the set $\Sigma :=\mathcal{M}$/~ of equivalence classes is a metric space when equipped with the distance $D(E_1,E_2)=\mu(E_1\Delta E_2)$.

I don't clearly understand the definition of the set $\Sigma$. Can anyone offer an intuition? Thank you very much guys!

Comment: If $[E] = \{ F | F \sim E\}$, then $\Sigma = \{ [E] \}_{E \in {\cal M}}$. The distance is sloppily defined. Given the distance above, define $\tilde{d}([E_1],[E_2]) = D(E_1,E_2)$. You need to show that this is well defined, that is, if $E_k \sim E_k'$ then $D(E_1,E_2) = D(E_1',E_2')$.

Comment: I don't know what you mean, the elements of $Sigma $ are subsets of ${\cal M}$.

Comment: No, this is the definition of $\sim$. You need to show that $\tilde{d}$ is a distance on $\Sigma$. First you need to show that the distance is well defined, then show that it satisfies the usual distance axioms.

Comment: Note that unless $\mu$ is finite, or the set ${\cal M}$ is restricted in some way, the above is not a distance as it may have the value $\infty$.

Comment: $\mu$ is finite. Can you give me a hint to prove this is well defined? I think i can prove the rest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that $\mu$ is finite.

Let $\tilde{d}([E_1],[E_2]) = D(E_1,E_2)$. We first need to show that $\tilde{d}$ is well defined.

Suppose $E_k \sim E_k'$. This means $\mu( E_k \triangle E_k') = 0$.

Note that $1_{A \triangle B} = |1_A-1_B|$ and $\mu A = \int 1_A d \mu$. If $E_k \sim E_k'$ then $\mu( E_k \triangle E_k') = \int |1_{E_k} - 1_{E_k'}| d \mu = 0$ and so $1_{E_k}= 1_{E_k'}$ ae. [$\mu$]. Hence
$\int |1_{E_1} - 1_{E_2}| d \mu = \int |1_{E_1'} - 1_{E_2}| d \mu =\int |1_{E_1'} - 1_{E_2'}| d \mu $ and so we have
$\mu( E_1 \triangle E_2) = \mu( E_1' \triangle E_2')$ and hence $\tilde{d}$ is well defined.

Since we have the formula $\tilde{d}([E_1],[E_2]) = \int |1_{E_1} - 1_{E_2}| d \mu$, it is straightforward to show that $\tilde{d}$ is a distance.

We have $\tilde{d}([E],[E]) = \int |1_{E} - 1_{E}| d \mu = 0$, and
$\tilde{d}$ is clearly non negative in general.

Since $|\cdot|$ is symmetric, it follows that $\tilde{d}$ is symmetric.

Since $|\cdot|$ satisfies the triangle inequality, it follows that $\tilde{d}$ does as well.